Is it permissible to speak while shaking the lulav and etrog in the sukkah?
After saying the bracha, is it permissible to speak while shaking the lulav and etrog in the sukkah?

Is the final condition on your question, "in the sukkah", davka?

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/137232/11532

It's forbidden to interrupt during Hallel (OC 488:1) which is when the Lulav is to be shaken (Mishna Sukkah 3:9). Don't see why the rule would change based on where you happen to be standing.
